# Custom Validator, should I use FacesContext#addMessage() or throw ValidatorException?

Tags: jsf, validation, jsf-1.2, custom-validators, facescontext

I was wondering what is the correct way of implementing the custom Validator in JSF 1.2. In my Validator class'

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,Object value) throws   ValidatorException {}
```

method, I am doing the validation check and just adding the `FacesMessage` instance to the context by `context.addMessage(new FacesMessage(xxx...);` in case of invalid condition. This seems to be working fine in my application. However, I am not sure if I also need to explicitely `throw new ValidatorException()` for JSF to handle the lifecycle correctly? Or would JSF be smart enough to look at the error messages in context to manage the lifecycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed be throwing a `ValidatorException`. Otherwise JSF will still continue processing the request and update the model values and invoke the action method. You don't want to have it.

Do not manually add the `FacesMessage`. Construct the `ValidatorException` with it and JSF will then automatically add the message to the right component and JSF will then correctly skip the *Update Model Values* and *Invoke Action* phases.

```
if (!valid) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid", null);
    throw new ValidatorException(message);
}
```

Comment: Is this still valid nowadays? I am writing a validator but I am having doubts whether to throw the ValidatorException or not.

Comment: @Douglas: yes certainly.